# How to access a button from an Activity in a fragment?

Tags: android

So I'm in a bit of a dilemma here,
I have a button in my DashboardFragment which can only be referenced within that class, and I need that button to enable bluetooth, which is done in a separate activity. I'd prefer not to have the Bluetooth code in my fragment class since the bluetooth will be referenced from multiple fragments. The issue is when I try to reference the Activity button from the Fragment class, I get a null object reference.
Here is my DashboardFragment class:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        connButton = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button2);



            connectionActivity = new ConnectionActivity();
            connectionActivity.initView(connButton);

    }
```

And my activity:

```
public class ConnectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = ConnectionActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    }

    public final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver1 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                        mBluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
                //Use for when implementing states
                switch (state) {

                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                        /*MainActivity.MyArrayAdapter adapter = (MainActivity.MyArrayAdapter) deviceSpinner.getAdapter();
                        if (adapter != null) {
                            adapter.clear();
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }*/
                        Log.d(TAG, "STATE OFF");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                        Log.d(TAG,"STATE TURNING OFF");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                        //populateDeviceSpinner();
                        Log.d(TAG,"I'm ON!");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                        Log.d(TAG,"Turning On...");
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public void initView(Button connButton) {

        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        connButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                enableDisableBT();
            }
        });
    }

    public void enableDisableBT() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Device does not have BLuetooth capabilites");
        }

        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBTIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivity(enableBTIntent);

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, filter);
        }
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
            registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver1, filter);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't refer to `views`associated with an `activity` (parent scope) from a `fragment` (child scope) because you can leak memory. If your `fragment` holds a reference to `activity` in the form of this `view`, then the `fragment` will never release the memory for garbage collection because of this reference.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. What would you suggest instead? I tried accessing that button from the ConnectionActivity, but it won't allow that since the button is associated with the dashboard fragment. Sorry, I'm really new to Android programming and I keep getting downvoted whenever I ask questions like these.

Answer (score -1):

Just add the reference in onViewCreated of DashboardFragment to

`((ConnectionActivity) getActivity()).initView(connButton)`